# accessing {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings. in mac osx

Tags: eclipse, macos, tomcat

i see that a solution to a [roblem with tomcat and server creation is to access "{workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings."
but i can't seem to see these folders... all i have in my workspace is project and a "RemoteSystemTempFiles" folder, please help?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On OS X files and directories with names which start with '.' are 'hidden' and Finder does not show them. You can see them in `Terminal` using the `ls` command, it is also possible to make Finder show hidden files (see for example [Show hidden files in OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/))